# Send two forms with ajax one submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have two forms on one page (one generated by one service so I can't change it).
I need when I sumbit form1 then firstly I send with Ajax, second form an after send second form send first form. I try to do it this way:

```
$('#form1').submit(function(event) {
            var this = (this);
            event.preventDefault();           
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: $('#form2').serialize(),
                success:function(data){
                    this.unbind('submit').submit();
                }         
            });
        });
```

The problem is, that I can't send first form after second one. Ajax ends with success, but first form are not send.

Thanks for help

Comment: Please spell out more clearly the desired order of events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things :

- `$.ajax()` returns a promise, so you can chain `.then(fn)`, which can make life easier with regard to the meaning of `this`.
- `form.submit()` will not retrigger the form's submit handler, therefore you don't need to unbind it.

Try this :

```
$('#form1').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
        data: $('#form2').serialize()
    }).then(this.submit.bind(this));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use promise to make it convenient.

```
function submitForm1 () { 
 return $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: $('#form1').serialize(),        
            });
}); 


function submitForm2 () { 
 return $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: $('#form2').serialize(),       
            });
});



submitForm2().done(function () {
    submitForm1();
});
```

Comment: The question does not indicate that form1 should be submitted with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Your form does not get sent because the `this` keyword in your success function will not be referencing your form element and so your function calls with it are erroring out.

Also `this` is a reserved word you cannot use it as a variable

```
var this = (this);
//change to
var that = this;
```

You can set the execution context of the success function a couple ways

1. Pass the context in the ajax options

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
      //...
      context: jQuery("#form1"),
      success:function(data){
         this.unbind("submit").submit();
      }
   })
   ```
2. Use the bind function

   ```
   jQuery.ajax({
       //...
       success: function(data){
          this.unbind("submit").submit();
       }.bind(jQuery("#form1"))
   });
   ```
3. Use a saved reference of `this`

   ```
   var that = this;
   jQuery.ajax({
      //...
      success:function(data){
          jQuery(that).unbind("submit").submit();
      }
   });
   ```